# Removing duplicates between sublists

Tags: matrix, functional-style

I want do delete from each sublist those elements which are contained in one or more of the other sublists. The surviving elements must maintain their original order of appearance.

```
list = {{6, 6, 4, 1, 7}, {1, 1}, {3, 1, 7, 2, 3, 7}, {-1}};
```

Expected result:

```
{{6, 6, 4}, {}, {3, 2, 3}, {-1}}
```

`UniqueElements`, released with with V 13.1, came to my mind,

```
UniqueElements[list]
```

{{6, 4}, {}, {3, 2}, {-1}}

but it also removes duplicates inside the sublists, and I didn't find a presentable way to overcome this.

How could a functional solution look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something along these lines maybe?

```
MapThread[Cases[#1, Alternatives @@ #2] &, {list, UniqueElements[list]}]
```

Or

```
MapIndexed[Select[#1, Function[{x}, FreeQ[Delete[list, #2], x]]] &, list]
```

Or

Nevermind, @kglr beat me to the DeleteCases strategy.

Comment: Acceptance is for the `MapThread`-solution - and thanks to everybody

Answer (score 6):

```
uniqueToParentList = 
     MapIndexed[DeleteCases[Alternatives @@ Flatten @ Drop[list, #2]] @ # &];


uniqueToParentList @ list
```

> ```
> {{6, 6, 4}, {}, {3, 2, 3}, {-1}}
> ```

```
uniqueToParentList2 = MapIndexed[DeleteElements[#, Flatten@Drop[list, #2]] &]

uniqueToParentList2 @ list
```

> ```
> {{6, 6, 4}, {}, {3, 2, 3}, {-1}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Probably much more mathematica-like ways to do this. I think using `MemberQ` as a test could be slow but I am not sure on this.

```
l = Length@list;
uE = UniqueElements[list];

Table[Select[list[[i]], MemberQ[uE[[i]], #] == True &], {i, l}]
(*{{6, 6, 4}, {}, {3, 2, 3}, {-1}}*)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
list = {{6, 6, 4, 1, 7}, {1, 1}, {3, 1, 7, 2, 3, 7}, {-1}};

sf[k_List, excl_List] := Select[k, FreeQ[excl, #] &]

sf @@@ ({Flatten@First@#, Union @@ Last@#} & /@ 
   Table[TakeDrop[list, {i, i}], {i, Length@list}])
```

---

**Using `ReplaceList`:**

```
ReplaceList[list, {g___, x_, h___} :> sf @@ {x, Union @@ {g, h}}]
```

---

*Result*

> {{6, 6, 4}, {}, {3, 2, 3}, {-1}}

Answer (score 3):

```
f = x |-> Select[First@x, FreeQ[Flatten@Rest@x, #] &];
f[RotateLeft[list, #]] & /@ Range[0, Length@list - 1]
(*{{6, 6, 4}, {}, {3, 2, 3}, {-1}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
MapApply[DeleteElements[#1,Flatten[{##2}]]&]@NestList[RotateLeft,
  #,Length@#-1]&@list

(* {{6,6,4},{},{3,2,3},{-1}}
```

or

```
MapApply[DeleteElements[Catenate@#1,Flatten@#2]&]@Function[x,
  TakeDrop[x,{#}]&/@Range@Length@x]@list

(* {{6,6,4},{},{3,2,3},{-1}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you can use `Subsets`, `Intersection` and `DeleteDuplicates` to find all excluded numbers, accordingly with your particular condition:

```
f = DeleteDuplicates[Sequence @@@ Map[Intersection[#[[1]], 
    #[[2]]] &, Subsets[#, {2}]]] &;
```

Finally, using `ReplacePart`:

```
ReplacePart[#, Position[#, Alternatives @@ f@#] &@# -> Nothing] &@list

(*{{6, 6, 4}, {}, {3, 2, 3}, {-1}}*)
```